# python: how to turn a dict list into a json file?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, openpyxl

'''

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
import itertools
import sys
import warnings
import json

def find (param):
    for row in ws.iter_rows():
        try:
            keyword = row[1].value
            values = [item.value for item in row[2:]]
            if keyword == ("%s" %(param) ):
                keyword = (values)
                return keyword
        except (AttributeError):
        continue

if not sys.warnoptions:
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

Tk().withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename()
print ("Working, please be patient")
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, data_only=True)


print ("\r")
count = 0
for ws in wb.worksheets:
    tlist = ws.title
    print ("%s : %s" %(count,tlist) )
    count = count + 1


x = int(input ("\nchoose number:  ") )
ws = wb.worksheets[x]


param = "Site Name"
SiteName = find(param)
SiteName = (SiteName)

param = ("NE Name(TID)")
TID = find(param)
TID = (TID)

param = ("Shelf Number")
SH_Num = find(param)
SH_Num = (SH_Num)

param = ("CLLI")
CLLI = find(param)
CLLI = (CLLI)

z = {'SiteName' : SiteName,"TID" : TID, "SH_Num" : SH_Num}

with open('data7.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(z,f,indent=4)
'''
```

There are alot more variables that will be in this. Every site has a site name, TID, shelf number, etc.. 
Wanting to separate the variables by the sites; variables for site 1, variables for site 2, etc.. and access the variables by TID1-SH_Num1[TID]

OUTPUT =

```
{
    "SiteName": [
        "Site1", 
        "Site2", 
        "Site3", 

    ], 
    "TID": [
        "TID1", 
        "TID2", 
        "TID3", 
    ], 
    "SH_Num": [
        "SH_Num1", 
        "SH_Num2", 
        "SH_Num3", 

    ]
}
```

What I am wanting is

```
{
    TID1-SH_Num1: [
        "SiteName" : "SiteName1"
        "TID": "TID1" 
        "SH_Num" : "SH_Num1"
        ], 
    TID2-SH_Num2: [
        "SiteName" : "SiteName2"
        "TID": "TID2" 
        "SH_Num" : "SH_Num2"
        ], 
    ], 
    TID3-SH_Num3: [
        "SiteName" : "SiteName3"
        "TID": "TID3" 
        "SH_Num" : "SH_Num3"
        ], 
}
```

etc..

I do have it where the individual sites variables are in separate text files for every site and the variables are all correct per site. Wanting it in JSON now, so I can add all of the sites and variables into tkinter tabs

Comment: Your desired output is not valid JSON: `TID1-SH_Num1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a dict like this:

```
a = {
"TID1-SH_Num1": [
    "SiteName" : "SiteName1"
    "TID": "TID1" 
    "SH_Num" : "SH_Num1"
    ], 
"TID2-SH_Num2": [
    "SiteName" : "SiteName2"
    "TID": "TID2" 
    "SH_Num" : "SH_Num2"
    ], 
], 
"TID3-SH_Num3": [
    "SiteName" : "SiteName3"
    "TID": "TID3" 
    "SH_Num" : "SH_Num3"
    ], 
}
```

Then you can just dump it into a file:

```
import json
with open('data7.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(a,f,indent=4)
```

Comment: That is how I am wanting it

Comment: Then you should add the appropriate keys to each one of your inner dicts, as I wrote

Comment: If this answer helped you, please consider accepting it

Comment: it is not in that format right now, but I am wanting it in that format